# Page is completley unreponsive

Tags: jquery, html

H, I am using jQuery Mobile to build a web app. I am having a problem with one of the pages.

i have this code:

```
<div id="timer" data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
        <a href="#menu" data-role="button">Menu</a>
        <h2>Timer</h2>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <a href="#" id="startStop" data-role="button"> Start</a>
        <div class="ui-grid-a" data-type="horizontal">
            <div class="ui-block-a">
                <input type="text" id="tHours" placeholder="HH" value="01"/>
                <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                    <a href="#" id="hPlus" data-role="button" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="notext">plus</a>
                    <a href="#" id="hMinus" data-role="button"data-icon="minus" data-iconpos="notext">delete</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b">
                <input type="text" id="tMinutes" placeholder="MM" value="00"/>
                <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                    <a href="#" d="mPlus" data-role="button" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="notext">plus</a>
                    <a href="#" d="mMinus"data-role="button"data-icon="minus" data-iconpos="notext">delete</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

when testing this page, I found that nothing happened.

when I move my mouse over the buttons and text boxes on the page I don't even get the little hand that signifies I can click.

can anybody see a problem with this code?
thanks

Comment: Is there any additional styling or libraries? It would be helpful if you could put together a representative JSFiddle. I tried using just that HTML and including jQuery mobile but it seemed to respond fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wow i am having a bad day.

I discovered my styling for the page had `z-index: -1;`

removing this line fixed the problem